# Python Polars : Update one dataframe with another (like Pandas .update() function)

Tags: python, python-polars

I have two dataframes. The first one is with all zero values and the second one, with actual values. I wish to update first dataframe with values from the second one, like Pandas .update function.

Here is the sample dataframe which I am using for illustration. These dataframes represent research databases and used to tabulate results.

```py
    dict = { 'state': 
        ['state 1', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', 'state 5', 'state 6', 'state 7', 'state 8', 'state 9', 'state 10'],
         'development': ['Low', 'Medium', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High', 'Low', 'Medium', 'Medium', 'Low', 'Medium'],
         'investment': ['50-500MN', '<50MN', '<50MN', '<50MN', '500MN+', '50-500MN', '<50MN', '50-500MN', '<50MN', '<50MN'],
         'population': [22, 19, 25, 24, 19, 21, 33, 36, 22, 36],
         'gdp': [18, 19, 29, 23, 22, 19, 35, 18, 26, 27]
        }

    df = pl.DataFrame(dict)
    df.head()
```

A table may be generated on filtered dataframe. It may not have a few rows and / or columns due to zero records. My aim is not to allow code to suppress rows / columns with blank values. Hence I create a blank dataframe 'tabstr' using the following code

```py
    row = df['development'].unique().to_list()        # Faster than pl.col twice
    col = df['investment'].unique().to_list()
    data = np.zeros( (len(row), len(col)), float)
    tabstr = pl.concat([
        pl.DataFrame({'development': row}), 
        pl.DataFrame(data, schema=col)], how='horizontal')

Now I create a pivot table on a filtered dataframe

    df2 = df.filter(pl.col('development') != 'High')
    _ct = df2.pivot(index='development', columns='investment', values='gdp')
```

I am using the below code to update the blank table `tabstr` using pivot table _ct

```py
    (
        tabstr
        .join(_ct, on="development", how="left", suffix = '_right')
        .with_columns(
            pl.coalesce([pl.col("<50MN_right"),pl.col("<50MN")]).alias("<50MN")
        )
        .drop("<50MN_right")
    )
```

Above code updates a single column. How can I loop through the columns of `tabstr` and update them using _ct columns, designated with suffix of '_right'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this code could move you closer to your answer.

Let's write two generic functions for `update`.   First, one in Lazy mode:

```py
from typing import Sequence
def update_lazy(self: pl.LazyFrame,
                updt_df: pl.LazyFrame,
                on: str | Sequence[str]) -> pl.LazyFrame:

    if isinstance(on, str):
        on = [on]

    common = set(self.columns) & set(updt_df.columns) - set(on)
    result = (
        self
        .join(
            updt_df,
            on=on,
            how="left"
        )
        .with_columns([
            pl.coalesce([col_nm + "_right", pl.col(col_nm)])
            for col_nm in common
        ])
        .drop([col_nm for col_nm in common])
        .rename({col_nm + "_right": col_nm for col_nm in common})
    )
    return result
```

And one in eager mode (that simply calls the Lazy mode):

```py
def update_eager(self: pl.DataFrame,
                 updt_df: pl.DataFrame,
                 on: str | Sequence[str]) -> pl.DataFrame:
    return self.lazy().update(updt_df.lazy(), on).collect()
```

I'll next assign them as methods to LazyFrame and to DataFrame.  (In your own code, you probably should use the namespace functionality in Polars -- but that's beyond the scope of this question.)

```py
pl.DataFrame.update = update_eager
pl.LazyFrame.update = update_lazy
```

Now we can call our functions (in either Lazy or eager mode) as methods:

```py
tabstr.update(_ct, on='development')
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────────────┬────────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ development ┆ 500MN+ ┆ 50-500MN ┆ <50MN │
│ ---         ┆ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str         ┆ f64    ┆ f64      ┆ f64   │
╞═════════════╪════════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ High        ┆ 0.0    ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0   │
│ Low         ┆ 0.0    ┆ 18.0     ┆ 29.0  │
│ Medium      ┆ 0.0    ┆ 18.0     ┆ 19.0  │
└─────────────┴────────┴──────────┴───────┘
```

You may need to tweak this code to suit your needs, but perhaps it will get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Here's another implementation: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6211#issuecomment-1419250004

Comment: It looks like this has been added in [version `0.16.3`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/6787) - useful stuff.